# Large File Read Memory Limit in .Net Unit Testing

Tags: c#, .net, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have a file which size 300 mb.
I read it from my console app but when I try into the unit test that time it throws out of memory exception.What is the difference between unittest and console app?They are running on same machine and they are both Debug/Any CPU and their target framework are same.

```
 var path = "C:\\my.xml";
string xmlString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Comment: IMHO there should not be any difference. Are you sure that the issue is up to size?

Comment: Your unit test project is being run by some sort of unit test adapter. For instance, if your unit tests use the NUnit testing framework and you're running in Visual Studio, you can use the [NUnit 3 Test Adapter plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NUnitDevelopers.NUnit3TestAdapter). The adapter contains its own code for running and recording the results of your tests, so that may be a difference compared to your console app.

Comment: Why are you be testing with such a big file?  How can you tell if the problem is the file or the code or the test?    You should test with smaller files.

Comment: Are you targeting 32bit?

Comment: Hi,I use default visual studio unittesting in windows 10.I just need a large file transfer and I hit the case and wonder why?

Comment: You need to find out what you are targeting to be honest. Typically this error happens well before you've consumed all available virtual memory. If indeed you are targeting 32bit OS, around 130Mb of reading you would hit OOM exception. Try targeting x64 and try it again.